# Unable to print in the desired manner using Pyperclip Module

Tags: python-2.7, pyperclip

I am using python 2.7.13. I am using Pyperclip Module to copy/paste text on a notepad (just for experimentation).

This is what I am trying to do:
    **a=['ayush','gupta']**
    **pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(a))** #It should print ayush and gupta in separate lines.
But I am getting output as:
    **ayushgupta** 
on the notepad.

If I try:
    **pyperclip.copy(' '.join(a))** #It works fine. I get **ayush gupta** with a space.

Could anyone please explain this.Thanks!!!

Comment: I am sorry if the question is not asked in the correct format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyperclip not pasting new lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464388/pyperclip-not-pasting-new-lines)

Comment: @jasonharper Yes I tried that, now it works fine. Thanks for the direction.