# Using Pyperclip in Python 3 Does Not Paste Data in Desired Format

Tags: python-3.x, pyperclip

I'm using python 3.7 and I want to:

- Copy IPs from a column in excel
- Add a comma between each IP separated by a space
- Return as one line
- Copy back to clipboard using pyperclip.

Below is the desired pasted results:

```
10.10.10.10, 10.10.10.11, 10.10.10.12, 10.10.10.13, 10.10.10.14
```

I have looked at some answers I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45714293/unable-to-print-in-the-desired-manner-using-pyperclip-module) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464388/pyperclip-not-pasting-new-lines) but it's not printing the desired results. Below, I have tried the following codes but none seem to do it for me:

```
#code 1
import pyperclip
text = pyperclip.paste()
lines = text.split('\n')
pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(lines))

#code2
import pyperclip
text = pyperclip.paste()
lines = text.split('\n')
a = '{}'.format(', '.join(lines[:-1]))
pyperclip.copy(''.join(a))

#code3
import pyperclip
text = pyperclip.paste()
lines = text.split('\n')
a = '{}'.format(', '.join(lines[:-1]))
pyperclip.copy(a)
```

Assistance on fixing this and understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
import pyperclip

text = pyperclip.paste()
lines = text.split()
pyperclip.copy(', '.join(lines))
```

Comment: Thanks! I was so focused on the last 2 lines that I overlooked the '\n' on the lines variable.